# android: PopUp Menu does not apply style

Tags: android, popupmenu

i have an Activity with an Action Bar. The Action Bar PopUp Menu (that appears after clicking the overflow button) applies my defined style.
But there is a EditText View inside my Activity, that should open a popup Menu by clicking on it.
This PopUp does not apply the style.

I hope someone can help me out..

Thx!!

Theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- ActionBar -->        
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/ActionBarPopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/ActionBarDropDownListView</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/ActionBar.Theme.actionbar.widget</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/mytheme_white_color</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/mytheme_white_color</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/ActionBarDropDownNav</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/ActionBarDropDownItem</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTextStyle</item>
    <item 

name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ns_actionbar_selectable_background_selector</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ns_actionbar_selectable_background_selector</item>

    <!-- Custom Items: -->

    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle_singleLine</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle_Default</item>
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/ns_CheckBoxStyle</item>
</style>
```

Styles:

```
<style name="ActionBarPopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_actionbar</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/ns_linearlayout_list_divider</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarDropDownListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_actionbar</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/ns_linearlayout_list_divider</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Theme.actionbar.widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/ActionBarPopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/ActionBarDropDownListView</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/mytheme_darkblue_color</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_spinner_item</item>
    </style>
```

Code for non workin PopUp::

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

......

userName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
userName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopupMenu(userName);
            }
        });

private void showPopupMenu(View v) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(LoginActivity.this, v);
        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, popupMenu.getMenu());

        popupMenu
                .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, item.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        popupMenu.show();

    }
```

Results:

[image: ActionBar Popup]

[image: EditText PopUp]

Comment: Have you found how to solve this problem?